# Show that $1={2^4+1^4+0\over 2!}-{3^4+2^4+1\over 3!}+{4^4+3^4+2\over 4!}-{5^4+4^4+3\over 5!}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How can we show that?

$$1={2^4+1^4+0\over 2!}-{3^4+2^4+1\over 3!}+{4^4+3^4+2\over 4!}-{5^4+4^4+3\over 5!}+\cdots$$

I try:

We know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{x^n\over n!}=e^x$

I wonder is there a closed form for $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{g^k(n)\over n!}=F(k)?$$

If there is one then it is easy to deduce the above proposed problem.

Any hints on where to start to tackle this problem?

Comment: Bell numbers, perhaps.

Comment: The general numerator $$(-1)^{n-1}(2n^4+4n^3+6n^2+3n)=2n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)+An(n-1)(n-2)+Bn(n-1)+Cn$$

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to hint me here @labbhattacharjee

Comment: @X-men, We need to identify $$A,B,C$$

Comment: I believe what lab bhattacharjee is trying to say is to change from the standard basis ${1,n,n^2,n^3,n^4}$ to another basis of ${1,n,n(n-1),n(n-1)(n-2),n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}$.  Then split the sum and cancel terms, like $\frac{n(n-1)}{n!}=\frac1{(n-2)!}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get 
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{n^4 + (n-1)^4 - (n-2)}{n!} t^n = 1+(2 t^4+8 t^3+8 t^2+t-1) e^t$$
This is the case $t=-1$.

EDIT: Let
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{n!} t^n = P_k(t) e^t$$ 
The polynomials $P_k(t)$ can be determined recursively since $P_0(t) = 1$ and
$$t \dfrac{d}{dt} (P_k(t) e^t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^{k+1}}{n!} t^n = P_{k+1}(t) e^t$$

Comment: How? A link to $\sum t^n n^k/n!$ would be nice. This kind of math is like magic - once you know the name, you can control it, or, in this case, look it up.

Comment: @X-men that is why he said that was the case where $t=-1$, if you plug in $t=-1$ you get the answer to your problem

Comment: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{n^4+(n-1)^4+(n-2)\over n!}(-1)^n=1$

Comment: ^What's wrong with his answer? If you plug in $t = -1$, then $2t^4+8t^3+8t^2+t-1 = 0$, and so, the sum is $1$, as desired.